# How to make two git branches (with common history) coherent with each other after rebasing one of them?

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, git-rewrite-history, tree-conflict

I think that my title is not clear enough, so I will describe the problem:

In my git project, I have 3 branches: `master`, `b1`, and `b2`. Here is the history tree:

```
 A---B---C  master
          \
           D---E---F  b1
                    \
                     G---H---I  b2
```

Suppose I want to rebase the `b1` branch and edit the `E` commit. After rebasing, commits `E` and `F` will be replaced by new commits `E'` and `F'` which have different commit SHAs. Therefore, the history in `b1` will be different from history in `b2`:

```
 A---B---C  master
           \
             D---E'---F'  b1
                     
 A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I  b2
```

So my question is: how to make sure that `b2` follows `b1` (automatically gets the same new commits as `b1`) after rebasing `b1` so that their respective histories stay coherent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your first rebase, it's not this:

```
 A---B---C  master
           \
             D---E'---F'  b1
                     
 A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I  b2
```

but rather this:

```
A---B---C  master
         \
          D---Ea---F'  b1
           \      
            E---F---G---H---I  b2
```

Here, `Ea` means the amended `E` commit.
And you want this, if I understand correctly:

```
A---B---C  master
         \
          D---Ea---F'  b1
                    \      
                     G'---H'---I'  b2
```

You can achieve this using an interactive rebase:

```
git checkout b2
git rebase -i b1
```

In the rebase edit you comment out the lines for commit E:

```
# pick df8efe6 E
pick a7fcbed G
pick 936b51a H
pick c77ca69 I

# ...
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# ...
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
```

Responding to your comment, if you want to go all the way from the starting position (ABCDEFGHI) to the desired end positon:

```
git checkout b2
git rebase -i master
```

In the editor:

```
pick 1234567 D
edit a7fcbed E
pick 936b51a F
pick c77ca69 G
pick 1e8d614 H
pick 8daafa7 I

# ...
# p, pick = use commit
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# ...
```

When done, correct the `b1` branch:

```
git checkout b1
git reset --hard 936b51a
```

You can also look at the other answers for inspiration. I'm not sure why you want to achieve all of this in a single command; you still have to amend commit E somewhere in the process. It saves you one interactive rebase to do it this way.

Comment: one extra note : when rebasing `b2` on `b1`, git should detect that `F` and `F'` introduce the same modifications ; in that case, `F` will already be dropped from the `rebase -i` list.

Comment: @LeGEC The rebase list (including E and F) is what I actually got when I tested this. Probably because the changed lines in te E->E' diff were to close to te D->E diff. Oh wait, I amended both E and F, that's why. Answer edited.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Now I would like to know if there is a way to do the whole process in one single command: rebase `b1` and automatically rebase `b2` according to `b1` changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two branches, with a linear history as in your diagram :

I would rebase `b2` instead of `b1` :

```
 A---B---C  master
          \
           D---E'---F'
                     \
                      G'---H'---I'  b2
```

and then update `b1` :

```
git branch -f b1 F'
```

---

@Han-KwangNienhuys answer is perfectly valid, and you can apply it if you need to update `b2` when `b1` has already been rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: how to make sure that b2 follows b1 (automatically gets the same new commits as b1).

You need to rewrite b2's history too, you're rebasing all of the `master..b2` commits and rehanging the `b1` and `b2` labels.

Interactive rebase lets you execute arbitrary commands, notably including `git branch`, after each step.  So do

```
git rebase -i master b2
```

and in the pick list after the current b1 commit say `exec git branch -f b1`.

You could automate this, pipe the picklist buffer through

```
while read command commit rest; do case $command in 
*) printf %s\\n "$command${commit:+ $commit${rest:+ $rest}}" ;;&
pick) git for-each-ref refs/heads --points-at $commit \
        --format='exec git branch -f %(refname:short)' ;;
esac; done
```

and it'll add the `exec git branch -f`'s after every pick for a branch tip. I've just built and tried this. Season to taste, of course.

If you're rebasing deep into a branched history, it's probably better to just construct the exact cherry-pick and branch sequence you want; rebase is a convenience command meant to ease a common task. Like all good tools it can be pushed a little farther than you might expect, but it's got its limits.